# How to use Whoosh or Flask-WhooshAlchemy as an autocompleting engine?

Tags: search, autocomplete, flask, whoosh

I'm using Flask building a site, and am using Whoosh as the search engine. Now I need an easy autocompleting engine to tag autocomplete, which I have tag `Python` with description `python programming language` stored. The description is used for assisting searching.

I can get the model by `whosh_search('python')`, but nothing got with `whosh_search('py')`.

How could I make `whoosh_search('py')` and `whoosh_search('language')` works just like an autocompleting engine?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20040977/how-to-use-n-grams-in-whoosh

Comment: I'd considered this, but didn't get a way to work with Flask-SQLAlchemy. Now i'm using ``ilike`` as a workaround.